# MySqlConnection Threading Optimization

Tags: c#, mysql, multithreading

How to optimize the functions that connect to the database so that if many users access the database at the same time, the server does not crash or create another problem.
Is it possible to use threading? Is it possible that if the database is late with the response, the main thread freezes or blocks other code?

```
public static void UpdatePassword(string email, string password)
    {
        using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(""))
        {
            connection.Open();
            MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();

            string saltedPassword = PasswordDerivation.Derive(password);

            command.CommandText = "UPDATE users SET password=@password WHERE email=@email LIMIT 1";
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", saltedPassword);

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use the Async version with `async\await` maybe? By the way, I hope you're not storing plain text passwords.

Comment: "*the server does not crash or create another problem*" - are you actually having this problem ?

Comment: Note that if you want `async`, you need to switch to https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/ because MySql.Data doesn't support async operations: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=70111

Answer (score 0):

In most situations, a single "program" should use a single connection to the database.  Having lots of "connections" incurs overhead, at least for creating the connections.

Async actions are rarely beneficial in database work since SQL is very good at working efficiently with millions of rows in a single query.

MySQL is very good at letting *separate* clients talk to the database at the same time.  However, this needs "transactions" to keep the data from getting messed up.

If your goal in C# is to get some parallelism, please describe it further.  We will either convince you that it won't be as beneficial as you think or help you rewrite the SQL to be more efficient and avoid the need for parallelism.